# Vimeo video in html 5 video tag on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, video

I have a jsfiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/fzzgjem4/5/

I have a vimeo video in a html5 video tag like in the example which is full width and play in the background.

This doesn't work on an ipad but just shows black box.

Is it possible to play a vimeo video in a html5 video tag on an ipad?

```
        <div class="video-block">

        <video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" autoplay muted loop></video>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<video>` is weird on iOS. You always need to use `controls = true` for it to work.
So it should look something like this:

```html
<div class="video-block">

  <video src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4" controls="true" autoplay muted loop></video>

</div>
```

At least, that's how it works with regular videos, not sure how using Vimeo changes its behavior. Unfortunately, that WILL add the Vimeo controls to the video, which means it sucks if you want to use it as a background to a div.